# c++ STL map.find() or map.operator[] cannot be used in class member function with const qualifier

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, constants, member

I'm confused by the following code, why it cannot be successfully compiled?

```
class Test { 
public:
  int GetValue( int key ) const
  {
      return testMap[key];
  }

  map<const int, const int> testMap; 
};
```

There is always a compling error:

```
error C2678: binary '[': no ​​operator found which takes "const std :: map <_Kty,_Ty>" type of the left operand operator (or there is no acceptable conversion).
```

I've tried to put const qualifier everywhere but it still couldn't pass. Could you tell me why?

Comment: 'map::find()' can be used in a const member function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`operator[]` is not `const`, because it inserts an element if one doesn't already exist with the given key. `find()` does have a `const` overload, so you *can* call it with a `const` instance or via a `const` reference or pointer.

In C++11, there is `std::map::at()`, which adds bounds checking and raises an exception if an element with the given key is not present. So you can say

```
class Test { 
public:
  int GetValue( int key ) const
  {
      return testMap.at(key);
  }

  std::map<const int, const int> testMap; 
};
```

Otherwise, use `find()`:

```
  int GetValue( int key ) const
  {
    auto it = testMap.find(key);
    if (it != testMap.end()) {
      return it->second;
    } else {
      // key not found, do something about it
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thx man, the code finally passed, replacing testMap[key] with testMap.find(key)->second;

Comment: @user2736504 beware, you have to check that the iterator returned by `find()` is not the end iterator.

Comment: also could use `rend()` ?

Comment: Thanks, this surely helps navigate the `const` surprises.

Answer (score 0):

You got an excellent answer by juanchopanza

Just wanted to show a `boost` way to return something that's not valid

with `boost::optional` you can return empty type

```
#include<boost\optional.hpp>
...

boost::optional<int> GetValue(int key){

    auto it = testMap.find(key);
    if (it != testMap.end()) {
      return it->second;
    } else {
      return boost::optional<int>();
    }
}


boost::optional<int> val = GetValue(your_key);
if(!val) //Not empty
{

}
```

Comment: Interesting, I'll try.